# NSIS installer: How to assosiate my own file format files (with my own file extension) to software (.exe) of my own?

Tags: installation, nsis, file-extension

My software uses a new file format that I have specifically developed for use with my software. The file has its own file extension
How can I attach this new file extension to my software .exe file in SetUp?
Of course this can be done manually by right-clicking on the file that has that new file extension. You can then search through the File Explorer for the exe program to which you want to associate this file extension. But it would be most convenient if the installer could do this.

Answer (score -1):

MSDN provides [all the details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/fa-file-types) about how file types work and how to register them.

The [install-per-user.nsi](https://sourceforge.net/p/nsis/code/HEAD/tree/NSIS/trunk/Examples/install-per-user.nsi) example that ships with NSIS registers a custom file extension.